# libgdx dialog how to properly display 3 lines and a button

Tags: button, text, libgdx, dialog

In a libgdx dialog I want to display three text lines, with a button to quit the dialog at the bottom.

The following code would print all text in 1 line, followed by the button at the bottom:

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Stats", skin);
    dialog.text("First line");
    dialog.text("Second line");
    dialog.text("Third line");
    dialog.button("Done");

    dialog.show(stage);
```

If I use table followed by a button like the following, the button would be shown at the left side not the bottom.

```
    Table table = new Table(skin);
    table.add(new Label("First line", skin));
    table.row();
    table.add(new Label("Second line", skin));
    table.row();
    table.add(new Label("Third line", skin));

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Stats", skin);
    dialog.add(table);
    dialog.button("Done");
    dialog.show(stage);
```

If I put a button inside the table the dialog can't be clicked close.

Comment: Use \n for a new line in your text.

Comment: While it will show in the next line, the second line start at the end of the first line.

Comment: ok just use dialog.text("first\nsecond\nthird"); and it works

Comment: That's what I meant, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it by table. Try

```
dialog.getContentTable().add(table);
```

If you want a text dialog. Follow this

```
Label text = new Label("first line\nsecond line\nthird line \n",skin,labelStyle);
text.setWrap(true);
```